# Assign variable by rendering as Number and not as text - Reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I have a following code. This is the rest of the react class component that shall be rendered.

```
 render() {
        return (
          <div>
            {this.state.todos.map((todo) => (
              <h1 id={todo.id} onClick={this.deleteTodo}> {todo.name} </h1>
            ))}
          </div>
        );
      }
```

I would like to have assigned `id={todo.id}` as number and not as text. Don't you know please, how to fix it?

Right now, it is actually like this: `id="1"`, but I would need that as `id=1`.

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 1):

It's very simple. Provided that the ID always comes as a number, then you can use the parseInt() function directly. It parses a string and returns an integer. So now it looks like this:

```
render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {this.state.todos.map((todo) => (
          <h1 id={parseInt(todo.id)} onClick={this.deleteTodo}>
            {todo.name} 
          </h1>
        ))}
      </div>
    );
  }
```

Comment: I'm glad to hear that. If it answers your question, don't forget to mark it as an answer. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

Use [Number](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number), the constructor contains constants and methods for working with numbers. Values of other types can be converted to numbers using the Number() function.

```
  <h1 id={Number(todo.id)} onClick={this.deleteTodo}> {todo.name} </h1>
```

Other option:

```
  <h1 id={+todo.id} onClick={this.deleteTodo}> {todo.name} </h1>
```

Comment: Thank you, both approaches are working perfect for me.